# Specify time interval in Django TimeStampedModel while Querying

Tags: python, django, postgresql, cron

I am trying to query my postgres database from django, I'm running a cron using custom management commands. I have a time stamped model called `Booking`, which has created at and modified at parameters, so that I know if the cron job has already been called for that particular booking. Now the cron job is called every hour, So what I need to do is to query my Booking model as

```
s = Booking.objects.all().filter(created_at = datetime.now())
```

is there a way I can specify a time range for created_at rather than a specific value, I want my range to be current time - 1 hour to current time.

I know that I can retrieve all objects and test all of them individually, I just wanted to know if there's a way to incorporate this into the Django query.

Comment: What version of django?

Comment: I am using django 1.7

Answer (score 6):

I found out the way after some research,

```
s = Booking.objects.all().filter(
    created_at__range=[datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=60), datetime.now()]
)
```

Django provides a functionality to provide range in queries, using variablename__range.